# Drupal Commerce - recreate taxonomy tree for product

Tags: commerce, taxonomy-terms

I've got existing website with catalog full of products. Each products have taxonomy term attached (catalog category). I've created views that will list products by additional option field. I've added field to product display which indicates that product is 'on offer' or it is for 'men' 'women' 'kids'. I can list all products teasers in a view using a filter. What I'd like to do is not to list products teasers but to re-create taxonomy on 'special offer' pages. So when someone goes to 'special offer' page it will show categories and subcategories and then product teasers. I thought about using taxonomy_get_tree() or maybe there's something like multiple parent per taxonomy so I can add a product to catalog and also to 'special offers'...

Comment: Why not to just create views pages for all those places? Views can operate both on fields and taxonomy structure.

Comment: But even if I list all main categories that have products 'on offer' if when I click category url i.e. catalogue/subcat1 this view will link back to normal catalog...